# SQL: Query formatting

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have a SQL query with three columns. The first is Year (categorical), the second is Site (categorical) and the last is temperature (float). The rows as unique combinations of Year X Site. For example:

Current query result

```
Year, Site, Temp
1,    1,  x11
1,    2,  x12
1,    3,  x13
2,    1,  x21
2,    2,  x22
2,    3,  x23
3,    1,  x31
3,    2,  x32
3,    3,  x33
```

I would like to have each site as a different column, while keeping years as rows. For example:

Desired query result

```
Year, TSite1, TSite2, TSite3
 1,    x11,    x12,    x13
 2,    x21,    x22,    x23
 3,    x31,    x23,    x33
```

Any ideas on how to do a query that results in this format? I would not mind using a temporary table or a view to store the information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Do you know all the sites beforehand?

Comment: asked and answered many times... hhttp://stackoverflow.com/search?q=turn+rows+into+columns

Comment: What you're looking for is a pivot/unpivot function.

Comment: I am using MySQL. Yes, I do know all the sites beforehand.

Comment: Then check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19525158/optimising-sql-queries/19527367#19527367). I think it is pretty clear

Comment: Mosty, thanks for pointing me to the answer. The MAX() function did the trick. I had tried before and did not work without it... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Mosty, any ideas how I would do the same if list of sites was not known, or extracted from a query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pivot query is one approach (as mentioned in the comments)  If you just want a comma-delimited list of sites, then you can do that with `group_concat()`.

```
select year, group_concat(temp separator ', ' order by site) as temps
from t
group by year;
```

I realize this may not be exactly what you want -- you lose the type information for `temp` by converting it to a string for example.  But then again, it may be what you need if you just want to see the temps or export them to another tool.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Year,MIN(CASE WHEN Site=1 THEN Temp ELSE 0 END) as Tsite1,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Site=2 THEN Temp  ELSE 0 END) as Tsite2,
        MIN(CASE WHEN Site=3 THEN Temp  ELSE 0 END) as Tsite3 FROM table GROUP BY Year
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input. The trick is the MIN() [alternatively also MAX()] function, without which would not work. Best!

Comment: Mihai, any idea how I would do the same if the list of sites was not known, or extracted from a query?

Comment: I doubt it can be done if sites are not known,but ask a new question with more details if you need it.