# Multiple rows, some have identical IDs, to separate columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

Working in Access 2013. I have an Excel file laid out like this:

```
ID  | Name  | Major   | Email
----+-------+---------+-----------------------
005 | Bobby | English | coolEmail@email.com
006 | Sarah | Math    | email@email.com
006 | Sarah | Science | email@email.com
007 | James | Art     | badEmail@email.com
```

and I would like for it to end up like this

```
ID  | Name  | Major 1 | Major 2 | Email
----+-------+---------+---------+----------------------
005 | Bobby | English | (blank) | coolEmail@email.com
006 | Sarah | Math    | Science | email@email.com
007 | James | Art     | (blank) | badEmail@email.com
```

Anyone know how I would do that?

None of my searches on here have given me anything that works. I have tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9356374/mysql-multiple-rows-to-separate-fields) to no avail. I have no clue what I'm doing :(

Comment: For a database your first table is closer to how I'd expect it to be stored.  It needs normalising, but it will be easier to extract data from that table.  `SELECT COUNT(Major) WHERE Major = 'Science'` against `SELECT SUM(IIF(Major1='Science',1,0), IIF(Major2='Science',1,0))`.  Then someone decides they want a third major - you'll need to change the structure of the whole database.

Answer (score 2):

Might be some minor Access syntax issues in there but I think this should work. You would basically need a "staging" source table or the ability to query Excel directly.

```
insert into <destination> (ID, Name "Major 1", "Major 2", Email)
select
    ID, min(Name), min(Major), iif(max(Major) <> min(Major), max(Major), null), min(Email)
from <source>
group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tested this query and it looks like it does what you are looking for.  Replace TABLENAME with the name of the table you will be referencing in MS Access.

```
SELECT
    m1.ID
    ,m1.Name
    ,m1.major AS [Major 1]
    ,m2.major AS [Major 2]
    ,m1.Email

FROM
    TABLENAME AS m1
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    *
                    ,(
                        SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM TABLENAME AS x 
                        WHERE x.major > y.major AND x.id = y.id
                    ) + 1 as rank_nbr 
                FROM 
                    TABLENAME AS y
            )
        WHERE
            rank_nbr = 2
    ) AS m2 ON m2.id = m1.id

WHERE
    m2.major IS NULL OR (m1.major IS NOT NULL AND m2.major <> m1.major)
```

Comment: Misunderstood initial question.  shawnt00 has best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you linked the Excel data as a linked table, try this:

```
Select
    ID,
    [Name],
    Min([Major]) As [Major 1],
    Max([Major]) As [Major 2],
    Email
From
    YourLinkedTable
Group By
    ID,
    [Name],
    Email
```

For displaying *blanks*, expand like this:

```
Select
    ID,
    [Name],
    Min([Major]) As [Major 1],
    IIf(Max([Major]) = Min([Major]), Null, Max([Major])) As [Major 2],
    Email
From
    YourLinkedTable
Group By
    ID,
    [Name],
    Email
```